# How to move an image element using javascript and how to make it stay there

Tags: javascript, element

using javascript i want to click on a link, and then have javascript move an image element to some location.  Only problem im facing is that the image element won't stay there, why is that

sample javascript:

```
function move( e )
{  
    var clickedLink = e.target;    
    // getting location of clicked link.
    clickedLink.style.left = "200px";
    clickedLink.style.top = "200px";
}
```

css for the "clickedLink" element object in the function move above.

```
#clickedLink 
{
  left: 0px;  
  position: relative;
  top: -500px;
  z-index: 10;   
}
```

Comment: its kind of bulky, but any reason why the image element won't stay there? like any general reason behind this?

Comment: A general reason? Your code is wrong.

Comment: it's hard to tell unless there's code to look at, post a sample snippet so people can take a look and suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Target don't have a style option just change into e.

```
 function move( e )
{  
    var clickedLink = e.target;    
    // getting location of clicked link.
    e.style.top = "200px";
    e.style.left = "200px";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say it won't "stay there", you aren't trying to get it to stay there after the page refreshes w/o saving it's new location somewhere, are you?

UPDATE:
To store the location, it depends on why you're storing it.  You can store it in a cookie as others have suggested, but that will only save it for that one user, in that one browser, and only until they clear the cookies.

If you want to make a change that stays w/ the user across different browsers, or make it available to other users... then you'll need to persist the change to a server via Ajax and you'll have to have the server-side code load in the location settings, etc.

Comment: i c, so how do i save its new location?

Answer (score 0):

The changes made using Javascript will not persist over a page reload.

A permanent change must be made using the CSS, otherwise the element must be re-moved using Javascript every time the page is loaded.

You could save the client's preferences in a cookie, for example, then use the `window.onload` event to fire a function that checks the cookie, and updates the element accordingly.

Or, you could use a server-side script that generates an extra CSS file customized to fit the current user's preferences (assuming it's the same user) when they save.  Then, check for this file's existence when the page is loaded (again with server-side script).

The main point is, Javascript changes are only temporary since they happen one time on the client's browser.

Comment: i see, so how in the css, can i pass it the new position values determined in javascript?

Comment: You can't, really, since the CSS file is stored on the server, and the Javascript shouldn't be able to change it.

Comment: Not precisely true.  You could have the JS code post a call to a server-side service and then that server-side code edits the CSS (or affects whatever the CSS is created from, etc).  But from where the OP is apparently coming from, that's probably too much.

Comment: @Paul, @dave - Yep, you can use an ajax request to accomplish this on-the-fly, note you'll still need a page reload to re-style the CSS.

Comment: @steve - I was thinking of a paired approach of doing the move in JS, saving to the server.  Clientside change is still in effect, no need to force a reload.  Alternatively, you can always refetch the CSS via JS if you want to (DOM manipulation or otherwise).

Comment: @Paul - true.  I suppose I could have said, "permanently re-style the CSS".

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to persist in place after the page has refreshed, you'll need to store its location in a cookie and load it when the page loads.